# Spring autowire byType with util:list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I am learning spring (and following Spring in Action), As I was playing around to understand few concept; then I observed following behavior.

**Scenario:** 
I wanted to autowire a list property in a Class by using "byType" autowire option. so I created util:list bean; which successfully get injected... so no surprise here :). 
Then I added a new list property in the same class(of different class hierarchy: off-course); then that too get injected without doing any extra wiring.... :O

Can any body explain whats going on under the hood. 
Below is some code snippt.

```
   public interface Performer {
    public void perform();
}

public interface Instrument {
    public void play();
}


public class Show implements Audotorium {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Show.class.getName());

    List<Performer> performerList;
    List<Instrument> instruments;

    public void setPerformerList(List<Performer> performerList) {
        this.performerList = performerList;
    }

    public void setInstruments(List<Instrument> instruments) {
        this.instruments = instruments;
    }

    public void show() {
        Iterator<Performer> performerItr = performerList.iterator();
        while (performerItr.hasNext()) {
            performerItr.next().perform();
        }

        Iterator<Instrument> instrumentItr = instruments.iterator();
        while (instrumentItr.hasNext()) {
            instrumentItr.next().play();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring-context.xml");
        ((Show) context.getBean("show")).show();
    }
```

**Bean Configration:**

```html
    <bean id="juggler" class="com.learning.Juggler"/>
    <bean id="magcian" class="com.learning.Magician"/>
    <bean id="kenny" class="com.learning.Instrumentalist">
        <property name="song" value="bay finger bay finger"/>
        <property name="instrument" ref="saxphone"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="hunk" class="com.learning.OneManBand" autowire="byType">
        <property name="song" value="bay finger bay finger"/>
        <property name="instruments">
            <list>
                <ref bean="saxphone"/>
                <ref bean="guitar"/>
                <ref bean="harmonica"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="totalBeanBags" class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="#{performerList.size()}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="saxphone" class="com.learning.SaxPhone"/>
    <bean id="guitar" class="com.learning.GenaricInstument">
        <property name="instrumentSound" value="guitar sound"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="harmonica" class="com.learning.GenaricInstument">
        <property name="instrumentSound" value="harmonica sound"/>
    </bean>


    <util:list id="performerList"/>

    <bean id="show" class="com.learning.Show" autowire="byType">

    </bean>
```

**Output:**

```
JUGGLING 10 BEANBAGS
Showing some crazy magicSSsssSSSsss.....
Playing bay finger bay finger :  TOO TOO TOO
Playing bay finger bay finger :  TOO TOO TOO
guitar sound
harmonica sound
----Now its music time----
 TOO TOO TOO
guitar sound
harmonica sound
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
 <util:list id="performerList"/>
```

you create an empty list, it is not used, you could remove it.

You have one bean of type `Performer` the 'OneManBand'.

When spring tries to autowire `setPerformerList`, it automatically creates a list of type `List<Performer>` and uses it as parameter. Spring puts all beans of type `Performer` into that list.

A list of `Instrument` is created and injected the same way.

This is a very handy feature of spring, I use it offen to build registries that collect all beans of a certain type and act on them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,